# problem creating a database schema sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server

i have been trying to make a clone of a database with out data being copied. since presence of broken stored procedure i am getting errors while creating database running the script. I even have a issue of the database assembly? what is it and do we need it? what will be the best approach to generate tow scripts. one to create database with all tables, views, sp etc and next for script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this step.

```
Generate Script of Sp's,Views and tables
1. Right click your database 
2. Point to Task
3. Click Generate Scripts
4. Follow the instructions Provided (click next)
5. check tables/ storedprocedures / views you want to generate
6. Click Select All
7. Next then Script to new query window then finish.
```

Create New Database you want.
From the script generated replace USE ["Databasename"]  then execute.

Regards

Comment: thanks, i did this step but when i try to run the script i get lots of errors releted to broken stored procedure. how do i fix that. and i get error about the assembly not found.